# How to use a Lyapunov function to test stability of a non-linear system?

Tags: control-theory, nonlinear-system, stability-in-odes

Regarding the image below

[image: example]

I am struggling to see how differentiation of the Lyapunov function is carried out. I can see how

$$
\dot x_1 \frac {\partial V}{\partial x_1} + \dot x_2 \frac {\partial V}{\partial x_2} 
$$

is calculated in the first stage, but beyond that, the last $2$ lines seem like a big jump.

Can anyone provide clarity on this or a more detailed step by step method to using Lyapunov functions to test for stability?

Comment: I can't see how the last two lines follow on from the one before it. (so the first of the last 3 to the last 2),

Answer (score 3):

Your system is
$$m\ddot{x}+c|\dot{x}|\dot{x}+k_1 x+k_2 x^3=0$$
Define the two state variables as $$x_1=x\qquad x_2=\dot{x}$$ to get:
$$\begin{align}\dot{x}_1&=x_2\\m\dot{x}_2&=-c|x_2|x_2-k_1 x_1-k_2 x_1^3\end{align}\tag{$*$}\label{*}$$
Also note that if $$V=\frac 12m x_2^2+\frac 12k_1 x_1^2+\frac14k_2x_1^4$$ then
$$\begin{align}\frac{\partial V}{\partial x_1}&=k_1x_1+k_2x_1^3\\
\frac{\partial V}{\partial x_2}&=mx_2\end{align}$$
Now, to calculate $$\frac{\partial V}{\partial x_1}\dot{x}_1+\frac{\partial V}{\partial x_2}\dot{x}_2$$ you need to replace $\dot{x}_1$ and $\dot{x}_2$ from the equation $\eqref{*}$. The rest should be straightforward.